# What causes assertion 'GTK_IS_MENU_ITEM (child)' failed?

Tags: python, gtk, menubar

I am trying to create a Gtk.MenuBar in my Python application. [This](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/menus.html) is what I've used as a tutorial. The following is my code for creating the MenuBar:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import GTKSignal

__author__ = 'xiaolong'

from gi.repository import Gtk


class XLDMenuBar(Gtk.MenuBar):
    MENUBAR_UI_INFO = """<ui>
            <menubar name='MenuBar'>
                <menu action='FileMenu'>

                    <menu action='File_New'>
                        <menuitem action='File_New_Dictionary' />
                    </menu>

                    <separator />

                    <menuitem action='File_Open' />

                    <menuitem action='File_Save' />

                    <menu action='File_SaveAs'>
                        <menuitem action='File_SaveAs_Dictionary' />
                        <menuitem action='File_SaveAs_SearchResult' />
                        <menuitem action='File_SaveAs_SelectedVocables' />
                    </menu>

                    <menuitem action='File_Exit' />

                </menu>
            </menubar>
        </ui>"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group = Gtk.ActionGroup("toplevel_menubar_action_group")

        self.initialize_file_menu()
        self.add_file_menu()
        self.add_menu_action_handlers()

        # TODO: add other actions, so far only file menu

        self.load_ui_info()

    def initialize_file_menu(self):
        self.action_filemenu = Gtk.Action(name='FileMenu', label='File', tooltip='opens the file menu', stock_id=None)

        # file -> new
        self.action_filemenu_new = Gtk.Action(name='File_New', label='New', tooltip=None, stock_id=None)
        self.action_filemenu_new_dictionary = Gtk.Action(
            name='File_New_Dictionary',
            label='New dictionary …',
            tooltip='opens the dialog for creating a new dictionary',
            stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_NEW
        )

        # file -> open
        self.action_filemenu_open = Gtk.Action(
            name='File_Open',
            label='Open …',
            tooltip='opens the dialog for opening files',
            stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_OPEN
        )

        # file -> save
        self.action_filemenu_save = Gtk.Action(
            name='File_Save',
            label='Save',
            tooltip='saves current changes of the dictionary to the dictionary file',
            stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_SAVE
        )

        # file -> saveas
        self.action_filemenu_saveas = Gtk.Action(name='File_SaveAs', label='Save As', tooltip=None, stock_id=None)
        self.action_filemenu_saveas_dictionary = Gtk.Action(
            name='File_SaveAs_Dictionary',
            label='Save dictionary as …',
            tooltip='saves the current dictionary with current changes to a specified file',
            stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_SAVE_AS
        )
        self.action_filemenu_saveas_searchresult = Gtk.Action(
            name='File_SaveAs_SearchResult',
            label='Save search result as …',
            tooltip='saves the current search result to a specified file',
            stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_SAVE_AS
        )
        self.action_filemenu_saveas_selectedvocables = Gtk.Action(
            name='File_SaveAs_SelectedVocables',
            label='Save selected vocables as …',
            tooltip='saves the currently selected vocables to a specified file',
            stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_SAVE_AS
        )

        # file -> exit
        self.action_filemenu_exit = Gtk.Action(
            name='File_Exit',
            label='Exit',
            tooltip='Closes the application',
            stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_QUIT
        )

    def add_file_menu(self):
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group.add_action(self.action_filemenu)
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group.add_action(self.action_filemenu_new)
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group.add_action_with_accel(action=self.action_filemenu_new_dictionary, accelerator=None)
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group.add_action(self.action_filemenu_open)
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group.add_action(self.action_filemenu_save)
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group.add_action(self.action_filemenu_saveas)
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group.add_action(self.action_filemenu_saveas_dictionary)
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group.add_action(self.action_filemenu_saveas_searchresult)
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group.add_action(self.action_filemenu_saveas_selectedvocables)
        self.toplevel_menubar_action_group.add_action(self.action_filemenu_exit)

    def add_menu_action_handlers(self):
        self.action_filemenu_new_dictionary.connect(GTKSignal.ACTIVATE, lambda widget: print('You\'ve clicked \"New dictionary\"!'))
        self.action_filemenu_exit.connect(GTKSignal.ACTIVATE, lambda widget: print('You\'ve clicked Exit!'))
        # TODO: add other action handlers

    def load_ui_info(self):
        uimanager = self.parent.create_ui_manager()
        uimanager.insert_action_group(self.toplevel_menubar_action_group)

        menubar = uimanager.get_widget("/MenuBar")

        vertical_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        vertical_box.pack_start(child=menubar, expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)

        self.add(vertical_box)
```

However, when I try to instanciate and add to my main window, I get the following assertion fail:

```
(__main__.py:12392): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_shell_insert: assertion 'GTK_IS_MENU_ITEM (child)' failed
```

To me it sounds, as if it says, that I am trying to add a non `MenuItem` to a `Menu`, but I cannot find that in my code. In the example on the tutorial website, they added `Gtk.Action`s to `Gtk.ActionGroups` just like I do, but their code does not cause this assertion to fail. I also checked the UI XML multiple times already and there is no `menu` to which I am trying to add a non `menuitem` or non `menu`, so I don't really know what's happening.

Where is the mistake I am making?

**EDIT#1**

To add a working example, I'll insert the code for the main application window and the call of it.

The main application window:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gui.XLDMenuBar import XLDMenuBar

__author__ = 'xiaolong'


class XLDMainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    WINDOW_TITLE = 'Xiaolong Dictionary'
    DEFAULT_X_SIZE = 400
    DEFAULT_Y_SIZE = 300
    menubar = None

    def __init__(self):
        # super().__init__(title='Xiaolong Dictionary')
        super(XLDMainWindow, self).__init__(title=self.WINDOW_TITLE)

        self.set_default_size(self.DEFAULT_X_SIZE, self.DEFAULT_Y_SIZE)

        self.initialize_widgets()
        self.add_widgets()

    def initialize_widgets(self):
        self.menubar = XLDMenuBar(self)

    def add_widgets(self):
        self.add(self.menubar)

    def connect_signals(self):
        pass

    def create_ui_manager(self):
        uimanager = Gtk.UIManager()

        # Throws exception if something went wrong
        uimanager.add_ui_from_string(XLDMenuBar.MENUBAR_UI_INFO)

        # Add the accelerator group to the toplevel window
        accelgroup = uimanager.get_accel_group()
        self.add_accel_group(accelgroup)
        return uimanager
```

And the call for creating the application itself:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gtkplustool import GTKSignal
from gtkplustool.gui.XLDMainWindow import XLDMainWindow

__author__ = 'xiaolong'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xld_main_window = XLDMainWindow()
    xld_main_window.connect(GTKSignal.DELETE, Gtk.main_quit)
    xld_main_window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

and the GTKSignal file I created:

```
__author__ = 'xiaolong'

DELETE = 'delete-event'
CLICKED = 'clicked'
ACTIVATE = 'activate'
```

Inserted into the correct directory structure, these files should be a working example. I have the directories set up as follows:

```
gtkplustool --> __main__.py
gtkplustool --> GTKSignal.py
gtkplustool --> gui --> XLDMainWindow.py
gtkplustool --> gui --> XLDMenuBar.py
```

Comment: Can you provide a *working* example? Including a minimal window you are using for it.

Comment: I'll try. Editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears because of the line `self.add(vertical_box)` in XLDMenuBar.py where you are trying to add a Gtk.Box (not a menu item) to the MenuBar.

To get it working, you can simply remove this line and the three above and modify your XLDMainWindow.py to the following (and make uimanager a class attribute):

```
    def add_widgets(self):
        menubar = self.uimanager.get_widget("/MenuBar")
        box = Gtk.VBox()
        box.pack_start(menubar, False, False, 0)
        self.add(box)
```